# Retrieving Dictionary<string, int> from app.config using DictionarySectionHandler

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I am trying to store a Dictionary in app.config. It would be very useful to avoid having to parse each string by while using NameValueCollectionSectionHandler, so I was looking instead at DictionarySectionHandler.

I have been able to import a Hashtable, but it seems I can only get string values. Is there a way to get to a Dictionary directly without parsing everything?

Is there anyway to import a Dictionary directly? I cannot seem to get DictionarySectionHandler to give me an actual Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

DictionarySectionHandler will always return an HashTable

You just have to transform it to a Dictionary using the types that you want

For examples if your Dictionary values are integer you could do

```
Dictionary<string,int> targetDictionary = sourceHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(d => (string)d.Key, d => (int)d.Value);
```